# Qt: out-of-line definition of "closeEvent" does not match any declaration in "MainWindow"

Tags: c++, qt

I just want to ignore the closing event thrown by the user in Qt, C++

I tried what is already in [the docs of Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#closeEvent)

```cpp
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    event->ignore();
}
```

But this throws me the error `out-of-line definition of "closeEvent" does not match any declaration in "MainWindow"`. I'd expect to ignore the closing event.

The header file:

```cpp
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
-
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: what do u mean is not working:???

Comment: I meant that throws the error cited in the title

Comment: Could you please post `MainWindow` class? It would seem `closeEvent` is not declared there.

Comment: How is `closeEvent` declared in the header file?

Comment: i thought it was declared by Qt... By the way, i put the header file in the post

Comment: It is, but in QWidget. If you want to override that protected virtual method in your own class, you have to declare it.

Comment: `QWidget::closeEvent` is declared by Qt. You have to declare `MainWindow::closeEvent` yourself, in the `MainWindow` class definition. This will override Qt's definition (because `QWidget::closeEvent` is a virtual function).

Comment: How can i declare it? void <code>MainWindow::closeEvent</code> as you have seen doesn't work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is that you need to declare in the header file that you will override the closeEvent. In the docs you can se that is virtual protected, that means that you can override it.

Your code should be the following:

The header file:

```cpp
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) override;

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
-
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

The cpp file:

```cpp
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    event->ignore();
}
```

Comment: Interesting, it worked. But, why does it have to be like this? Being a C# programmer, still cannot understand why inheritance (or interface implementations) does not work the same way. Can someone explain it please? Thanks in advance!